# How to create list of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

How to create a list of checkbox and retrieve selected checkbox value in javascript

Comment: Are you asking how to create a group of checkboxes in HTML and then get the selected value using javascript or do you want to dynamically create them with javascript as well?

Comment: @ryanulit..
I dont want to create it dynamically...!!!
simply creating a list of checkboxes in html

Comment: Oh? I'd suggest to go through a HTML tutorial as well. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: I'd suggest a *decent* tutorial: http://wsc.opera.com/ (W3Schools is error prone and full of adverts that look (until you are half way through reading them) like they are part of the tutorial)

Comment: htmldog.com is another great one as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presuming a structure like:

```
<form name="test">
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="red"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="orange"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="yellow"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue"/>
</form>
```

Then use something like this to retrieve the value:

```
var values = [];
var cbs = document.forms['test'].elements['colors'];
for(var i=0,cbLen=cbs.length;i<cbLen;i++){
  if(cbs[i].checked){
    values.push(cbs[i].value);
  } 
}
alert('You selected: ' + values.join(', '));
```

Comment: `id` is preferred to `name` for identifying forms.

Comment: @David (preferring id over name) is this just for simplicity? using the name attribute is fine, as is accessing by index if you know the position.  If however I was to use the document.getElementById(id) function then I would surely use an id.  Hmm, after peeking at the W3C I see that maybe name is on the way out in favor of id in the future. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-name-FORM

Comment: @David : personnaly, I don't always give id's to my forms elements, but always a name.

Comment: In the ancient days when Netscape ruled the land, `name` was used all over the place. Then HTML standardized on using `name` for form **controls** and `id` and `class` for scripting. XHTML 1.0 **removed** the name attribute from forms and XHTML 1.1 removed it from anchors (so you example is invalid if it is supposed to be XHTML (I can't speak for the HTML5 draft without checking, but its a draft anyway)).

Comment: Thanks @David - its an interesting question... XHTML did remove it, but as we now know... XHTML is slowly becoming a dead end in favor of HTML5.  In HTML5, the name attribute is still there http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-form-element (and currently does not include any deprecation info or warnings against using it).  That all said, since the name attribute isn't actually used in the form submission, an id attribute is likely more useful.

Comment: Edit queue is full - answer needs to be fixed. The `"` and `'` don't match.

Comment: Fixed the quotes @GrantCurell, nice catch.

Comment: Does not work if there is only one `<input>` (e.g. red) in the `<form>`. Why? Can you fix it? UPD: Why in case of one input the `length` is undefined?

Comment: Browsers decided that if there is only 1 checkbox (or radio button), you should access the `.checked` and `.value` properties directly as an atomic field vs. as an array and as such there won't be a `.length` property. IMHO this was a terrible design, but alas we are stuck with it. I'll update this answer to handle both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

To create an element in DOM, use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createElement). To retrieve selected checkbox value, use [`element.checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/cn/XUL/Attribute/checked) and/or [`element.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/value). To learn more about HTML DOM, [start here](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp).

You may want to consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to ease all the DOM manipulation and traversing work.

Answer (score 1):

More modern answer

```js
document.querySelector("[name=test]").addEventListener("click", 
  e => {
    let tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.name==="colors") {
      let checked = [...e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll(`[name=${tgt.name}]:checked`)];
      document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = checked.map(inp => inp.value).join(", ")
    }   
})
```

```html
<form name="test">
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="red"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="orange"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="yellow"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue"/>
</form>
<span id="res"></span>
```