# list of checkbox-ids in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, bootstrap-4

How do I create a list in JavaScript, which contains all the checkbox IDs of my form?

I have one form, including multiple inputs (all checkboxes)

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721046/how-to-create-list-of-checkboxes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: `const list = [...document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]")].map(inp => inp.id)`

Comment: @mplungjan thanks a lot <3

Comment: If you need only the checked ones: `const list = [...document.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]:checked")].map(inp => inp.id)`